# How do I detect when the Xbox home button is pressed XNA?

Tags: xna-4.0, gamepad

How do I detect when the big Xbox button in the middle of the gamepad is pressed in XNA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about the [guide button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_Controller#Guide_button), it sounds like. The guide button is reserved, and you can't detect its state directly.

You can, however, detect if the guide is active so you can pause your game (or whatever). To do this, you'll want to have a look at the [IsVisible property of the Guide class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.guide.isvisible.aspx)